# Odd behiavior of USB interrupt interval on Linux

Tags: linux, debugging, embedded, usb

I'm developing a USB device driver for an embedded system, and the host is a Linux system (Ubuntu 21.04 for now). The device is based on an FPGA, a SmartFusion2. I'm using pyusb to test my device, and I check performance with Wireshark + usbmon.

The device is running in high speed mode, have several endpoints, and an interrupt IN endpoint in particular.
On this endpoint:

- with an interval setting in the descriptor of 32, my device get tokens every 32 ms (stdev ~50us). That's what is expected for low speed / full speed devices, so there is already something broken here, but otherwise the situation is acceptable.
- with an interval setting of 16 (or less), I get a whopping 4096 ms (stdev ~100 us). Very broken.

Those timing are independent of the device, I can reset the device and reconnect, the alignment with the previous 4096ms cycles is nearly perfect. They are also independent of pyusb start time, and timeout settings, so I'm thinking it's due to the linux USB host driver.

Is that normal?
How do I debug that?

I can post some Wireshark captures if needed.

My descriptors looks otherwise ok to me, but maybe I missed something:

```
sudo lsusb -v

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         3 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0003 3.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            5.11
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 5.11.0-22-generic xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:15.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x001f
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
        bMaxBurst               0
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              12
  bDescriptorType      42
  nNbrPorts             7
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  bHubDecLat          0.0 micro seconds
  wHubDelay             0 nano seconds
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 2: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 3: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 4: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 5: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 6: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 7: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x000f
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x02
      Latency Tolerance Messages (LTM) Supported
    wSpeedsSupported   0x0008
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   3
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat         512 micro seconds
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

-- Other device --

-- Other device --

-- Other device --

Bus 001 Device 083: ID 1514:fff0 Actel CLICK USB bridge
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass       255 Vendor Specific Subclass
  bDeviceProtocol       255 Vendor Specific Protocol
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1514 Actel
  idProduct          0xfff0 
  bcdDevice            0.01
  iManufacturer           1 MIT STARLab
  iProduct                2 CLICK USB bridge
  iSerial                 3 V0.1
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x002e
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval              32
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval              32
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval             255
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval             255
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass       255 Vendor Specific Subclass
  bDeviceProtocol       255 Vendor Specific Protocol
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

-- Other device --

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            5.11
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 5.11.0-22-generic xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:15.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0019
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              11
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             9
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
    TT think time 8 FS bits
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x00 0x03
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff 0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0503 highspeed power enable connect
   Port 2: 0000.0503 highspeed power enable connect <- *** My device ***
   Port 3: 0000.0503 highspeed power enable connect
   Port 4: 0000.0100 power
   Port 5: 0000.0100 power
   Port 6: 0000.0503 highspeed power enable connect
   Port 7: 0000.0103 power enable connect
   Port 8: 0000.0100 power
   Port 9: 0000.0100 power
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Comment: Hi pserra. Were you ever able to solve your issue?

Comment: Not yet. I moved to another host device (final hardware for the project), and I need to test that again. I will update the questions if I find anomalies again.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I cannot read the spec properly. The `bInterval` setting in the descriptor is a power of 2 of the actual time interval. For high speed mode:

```
time interval = 2 ** (bInterval - 1) * 0.125.
```

So for bInterval = 16, 4096 ms, as measured.

Also the maximum value for bInterval is 16, if higher linux sets it to 9 instead, and outputs something in dmesg:

> [  693.295727] usb 1-1.1: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x81 has an invalid bInterval 32, changing to 9

So `bInterval = 9` is 32 ms... as measured.